# Sending emails with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, email

I am using javascript to try send emails which contains HTML or attachments, but that's not possible with mailto:. So now I need some other way to send HTML or attachment with email. I found this email composer plugin to phonegap, which should work as I need it to work, but it doesn't open email application at all nor prompt window where you are able to select your email application.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
        function (isAvailable) {

            window.plugin.email.open({
                to:      'test@test.com',
                subject: 'Greetings',
                body:    'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig'
           }, callback, scope);
        }
    );
}, false);

function callback(){
    console.log("callback function");
}

function scope(){
    console.log("scope function");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure of the following:

### 1. Add plugin to your project:

Using command line, navigate to your project folder and run the following command:

> cordova plugin add
> https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git

.

### 2. Test using emulator or device:

Most Cordova plugins are not available for testing using web browser and require device or emulator to be available, make sure you test your code on device or emulator.

.

### 3. Use Remote Debugging:

Use remote debugging on chrome or safari to debug your application directly on your connected device and see what's going wrong.

> Chrome Remote Debugging:
> https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging
> Safari Remote Debugging: http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

.

### 4. See if email plugin is available:

Modify your code to display the value of the isAvailable variable and see if the email plugin is available or not in your testing environment.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
        function (isAvailable) {
            alert("is email mobile available? " + (isAvailable ? "Yes" : "No"));
            if(isAvailable){
             window.plugin.email.open({
                 to:      'test@test.com',
                 subject: 'Greetings',
                 body:    'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig'
             }, callback, scope);
           }
        }
    );
}, false);

function callback(){
    console.log("callback function");
}

function scope(){
    console.log("scope function");
}
```

Comment: I checked those steps one by one and really interesting, but now it is working. I have done steps 1-3 earlier, so I am not sure is it that one alert message what make it magically works OR that I set up (add email address etc.) to email software before trying this. What confuses me is that before setting email up, it didn't prompt that "what email application I want to use".

**TL:DR** Make sure you setup your email application if email-composer plugin isn't working.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I think to be sure what is the cause of the problem you could try removing your email account on device and see if the problem returns, otherwise, it's one of those steps mentioned above.